# Is there any way to check if the UserCredential is already logged in with a user name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using the google api v3.0

```
UserCredential uc = null;
UserCredential credential = null;
        private void UserCredentials()
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
            uc = credential;
        }
```

Then

```
private void UserYoutubeService()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
        }
```

And i'm calling this two methods in the my form constructor:

```
public Youtube_Uploader(string filetoupload)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileNameToUpload = @"C:\test.mp4";
            service = AuthenticateOauth(apiKey);
            var videoCatagories = service.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
            videoCatagories.RegionCode = "IL";
            var result = videoCatagories.Execute();
            UserCredentials();
            UserYoutubeService();
            MakeRequest();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Now i have some problems.

In the method UserCredentials this GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker will start the chrome browser but i need to do something that will check if it's already have the Credentials if so don't fire the chrome just show me on my program on my form that it have the the credentials and also show me the name of the credentials.

If the credentials empty then make the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker and fire up the chrome with this screen of google youtube api that ask the user to log in and then to accept.

Accept screen i mean the screen that say: This app would like to.....Cancel Accept

So maybe there is something like GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker that will not automatic fire chrome but only if there are credentials or not already.

And also something that will give me the current gmail account name if there are already credentials then show me on the form the name of the account.

If it's for example danny@gmail.com then show me something like: Connected to: Danny

But if i logged out my gmail account then it will show me the accept screen and log in screen to log into gmail account.

This is how i log out if a user logged in:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Revoke();
        }
```

Then:

```
public void Revoke()
        {
            if (uc!=null)
            {
                uc.RevokeTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            }

        }
```

Comment: trick here is "user" it identifies different users. your credentials are being stored in %appdata%

Comment: Maybe you can show me the solution how to make it. What i want to do is to check if a user is already logged in. If a user logged in display the user name and give me the options to log out. If a user is not logged in then give me the options show me the log in page and then the accept screen. I added to my question the method that i use for log out.

Comment: Welcome to stack. we are hear to help you fix errors in your code not do your work for your.     Your code as written will only remember the login of one user because you are hard codeing the word "user" which should probably be the email address or some kind of primary key to identify your user as being different from a different user.